# How to remove aliasing from two images displayed on top of each other in the video sequence editor?

Tags: video-sequence-editor, antialiasing

I have two images that are displayed one on top of the other in the video sequence editor:

[image]

Each image has an accompanying transform to apply scale and rotation:

[image]

On closer inspection of the rendered output of the first frame, I discovered a lot of aliasing where the two images overlap:

[image]

The `Blend` property of the top two strips is set to `Alpha over` and the other two strips have the value set to `Replace`.

How do I remove the aliasing so that there isn't such a visible seam when the images are blended together?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This seems to be a precision problem, when you check *Convert to float* in the filter tab of your image strips, the issue disappears.

[image]

Comment: I wonder why this isn't the default? I am maintaining an [addon for transforming strips in the VSE](https://github.com/doakey3/VSE_Transform_Tools) and I wonder if I should make my addon ensure this box is checked whenever a transform strip is added