# Sequence Editor Aliasing of downscaled clips

Tags: video-sequence-editor, antialiasing

I have a transparent image I would like to overlay on another background. When I downscale the image, it looks heavily aliased

[image: An apple on a black field, badly aliased]

Ideally, I would like a result more like what you'd expect with traditional downscaling:

[image: Downscaled apple.]

Already tried:

- [How to remove aliasing from two images displayed on top of each other in the video sequence editor?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/101920/how-to-remove-aliasing-from-two-images-displayed-on-top-of-each-other-in-the-vid), which doesn't seem to have any effect.

Comment: (I'm aware that the real answer might be "learn to use a different video editor--the sequence editor can only do so much" or "make a ticket and fix it yourself", but I'd like to check in case I'm missing something obvious.)